# How to concatenate two PDF in Apex

Tags: blob

Creating a map of Id and Blob in the following for loop from the Page which has renderAs="pdf"

```
for(Account acc : [query])
{
PageReference pdf = Page.AccountInvoice;
   pdf.getParameters().put('financialAccountCurrentValue',
    String.valueOf(acc.Financial_Account_Current_Value__c));
   pdf.getParameters().put('financialAccountList',JSON.serialize(acc.Client_Account__r));
   pdf.setRedirect(true);
   accIdVsBlobMap.put(acc.Id, pdf.getContent());
}
```

Now, in this for loop; I am sending the attachment by concatenating the above blob and following blob.

Refer "Kindly Notice From Here"   section which I have tried to slightly imitate after reading your Blog...But the problem is When I receive the email...Attachment contains only the first blob and not the second blob...Any help would be appreciable?

```
for(Contact c : [query]){
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
// Reference the attachment page, pass in the account ID
   PageReference pdf = Page.ContactDetail;
   pdf.getParameters().put('id',c.Id);
   pdf.setRedirect(true);

   Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
   efa.setFileName('invoice.pdf');

   *******************Kindly Notice From Here**************************************

   String header = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdf.getContent());
   String body = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(accIdVsBlobMap.get(c.AccountId));

   String last4Bytes = header.substring(header.length()-4, header.length());
   String fullpdf;

if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')){
Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody()+body;   
fullpdf = header.substring(0,header.length()-4)
+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter));
}else{
fullpdf = header + body;
}
      ***************************END ******************************
   efa.setBody(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fullpdf));

email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
email.setTemplateId(templateId);
email.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);
emailList.add(email);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one PDF, you'll need to send them as separate attachments. You can't just append one PDF to the next without "re-rendering" each page, then compiling a new PDF from within Salesforce unless you had a utility of some sort you can call that's the equivalent of Adobe Acrobat Pro. It just doesn't work that way.

There's much more to a PDF file than a collection of headers and a footers with code for the contents of each page's structure in-between them. In addition to detailed instructions for each page, a PDF document also includes a set of instructions for how to print the document as a whole. This would include things like pagination instructions for the entire document, color profile information for color matching, a list of the fonts used throughout the document, possibly including a full or subset copy of those fonts, along with a common page set-up and a number of other things. Bottom line, each page isn't totally self-contained.